# Database is locked - how to fix?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I set `fireBase` in my project and in `crashReporting` show bellow errors :

```
Exception java.lang.Throwable: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode ################################################################# Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY) Caused By : The database file is locked. (database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode) #################################################################
....data.source.local.DataBaseInstagram.insertToProductsDrafts (DataBaseInstagram.java:132)
```

And :

```
Exception java.lang.Throwable: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ProductsDrafts (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from ProductsDrafts ################################################################# Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: ProductsDrafts (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from ProductsDrafts) #################################################################
....data.source.local.DataBaseInstagram.insertToProductsDrafts (DataBaseInstagram.java:132)
```

And:

```
Exception java.lang.Throwable: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ProductsDrafts (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ProductsDrafts ################################################################# Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: ProductsDrafts (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ProductsDrafts) #################################################################
....data.source.local.DataBaseInstagram.selectFromProductsDraftsTable (DataBaseInstagram.java:283)
```

And:

```
Exception java.lang.Throwable: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5) ################################################################# Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY) Caused By : The database file is locked. (database is locked (code 5)) #################################################################
....data.source.local.DataBaseInstagram.selectFromProductsDraftsTable (DataBaseInstagram.java:283)
```

And bellow is my codes :

```
   public class DataBaseInstagram extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Instagram";


    //region Instagram table
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "DetailImage";
    private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME = "imageName";
    private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_ID = "imageID";
    //endregion

    //region Products drafts
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS = "ProductsDrafts";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE = "productPrice";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PREPARATION_TIME = "ProductPreparationTime";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "ProductQuantity";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_BRIEF_DESCRIPTION = "ProductBriefDescription";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = "ProductDescription";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_ID = "subCategoryId";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_TITLE = "subCategoryTitle";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES = "productProperties";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS = "Keywords";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PUBLISH_PRODUCT = "PublishProduct";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS = "ProductStatus";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS_ACTION_USER = "StatusActionUser";
    //endregion

    public DataBaseInstagram(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                        COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_IMAGE_ID + " TEXT" + ")";
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS + "(" +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_PREPARATION_TIME + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_BRIEF_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_ID + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_TITLE + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_PUBLISH_PRODUCT + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS_ACTION_USER + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS_TABLE);
        String INDEX = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX products_index ON "
                + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " (imageID)";
        db.execSQL(INDEX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Long insertToProductsDrafts(String productName,
                                       String productPrice,
                                       String productPreparationTime,
                                       String productQuantity,
                                       String productBriefDescription,
                                       String productDescription,
                                       String subCategoryId,
                                       String subCategoryTitle,
                                       String properties,
                                       String keywords,
                                       String publishProduct,
                                       String productStatus,
                                       Integer statusActionUser) {
        Log.i("SDASDADASDDS"," - " );
        Long id = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            int NoOfRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            if (NoOfRows > 0) {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            }
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE, productPrice);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_PREPARATION_TIME, productPreparationTime);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY, productQuantity);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, productBriefDescription);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, productDescription);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_ID, subCategoryId);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_TITLE, subCategoryTitle);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES, properties);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS, keywords);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_PUBLISH_PRODUCT, publishProduct);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS, productStatus);
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_STATUS_ACTION_USER, statusActionUser);
            id = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS, null, values);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
            FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (db != null) {
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
                db.close();
            }
        }
        return id;
    }

    public void deleteFromProductsDraftsTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            int NoOfRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            if (NoOfRows > 0) {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            }
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
            FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public Product selectFromProductsDraftsTable() {
        Product product = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            product = null;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Product.ProductProperty>>() {
            }.getType();
            String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    List<Product.ProductProperty> lsProductProperty = new ArrayList<>();
                    String productPropertyText = null;
                    List<Product.ProductProperty> propertyList = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(8) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(8))) {
                            productPropertyText = cursor.getString(8);
                        }
                    }
                    if (productPropertyText != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(productPropertyText)) {
                            propertyList = gson.fromJson(productPropertyText, listType);
                        }
                    }
                    if (productPropertyText != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(productPropertyText)) {
                            if (propertyList != null) {
                                if (!propertyList.isEmpty()) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < propertyList.size(); i++) {
                                        Product.ProductProperty productProperty = new Product.ProductProperty(
                                                propertyList.get(i).getId(),
                                                propertyList.get(i).getTitle(),
                                                propertyList.get(i).getMeasurementUnit(),
                                                propertyList.get(i).getValue());
                                        lsProductProperty.add(productProperty);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Boolean published = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(10) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(10))) {
                            published = Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(10));
                        }
                    }
                    Integer preparationTime = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(2) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(2))) {
                            preparationTime = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
                        }
                    }
                    String keywords = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(9) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(9))) {
                            keywords = cursor.getString(9);
                        }
                    }
                    Integer quantity = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(3) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(3))) {
                            quantity = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
                        }
                    }
                    Integer status = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(11) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(11))) {
                            status = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(11));
                        }
                    }
                    Product.ExtraInfo extraInfo = new Product.ExtraInfo(lsProductProperty,
                            published,
                            preparationTime,
                            keywords,
                            quantity,
                            status);
                    String name = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(0) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(0))) {
                            name = cursor.getString(0);
                        }
                    }
                    String price = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(1) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(1))) {
                            price = cursor.getString(1);
                        }
                    }
                    String briefDescription = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(4) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(4))) {
                            briefDescription = cursor.getString(4);
                        }
                    }
                    String description = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(5) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(5))) {
                            description = cursor.getString(5);
                        }
                    }
                    int subCategoryId = 0;
                    if (cursor.getInt(6) > 0) {
                        subCategoryId = cursor.getInt(6);
                    }
                    String categoryTitle = null;
                    if (cursor.getString(7) != null) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cursor.getString(7))) {
                            categoryTitle = cursor.getString(7);
                        }
                    }
                    product = new Product(name,
                            price,
                            briefDescription,
                            description,
                            subCategoryId,
                            categoryTitle,
                            extraInfo);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
            FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        }
        return product;
    }

    public Long insertToInstagramTable(String imageID, String imageName) {
        Long status = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_ID, imageID);
            values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME, imageName);
            status = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
            FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        }
        return status;
    }

    public List<ExistImage> selectFromInstagramTable() {
        List<ExistImage> lstExistImages = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            lstExistImages = new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ExistImage existImage = new ExistImage();
                    existImage.setImageName(cursor.getString(0));
                    existImage.setImageID(cursor.getString(1));
                    lstExistImages.add(existImage);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
            FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        }
        return lstExistImages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`SQLiteException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html)

> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

```
Exception java.lang.Throwable: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ProductsDrafts (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ProductsDrafts
```

Make sure **`ProductsDrafts`** is Present in Database.

**FYI**

If you add table after publish, then add [**`onUpgrade()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
if(newVersion>oldVersion)

 // ALTAR TABLE STATEMENT
 // DROP TABLE STATEMENT 

}
```

Comment: @JoJoRoid You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya. I update my question and edit onUpgrade() .Please see .Thanks a lot

Comment: @JoJoRoid set `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Instagram.db";`

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya. This code is true ?     @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS_DRAFTS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }